# How change dimname in R

Tags: r, xts, zoo

I have in my program one class table  "xts" and "zoo"  which is as follows

```
> head(BRA$Adj.Close)

           Adj.Close
2005-01-03     25722
2005-01-04     24848
2005-01-05     24692
2005-01-06     24367
2005-01-07     24747
2005-01-10     24292
```

I need add the dimname "Date" in this table, resulting in

```
 Date         Adj.Close
2005-01-03     25722
2005-01-04     24848
2005-01-05     24692
2005-01-06     24367
2005-01-07     24747
2005-01-10     24292
```

how I do it ?

Comment: You cannot. The first "column" is not a column. See the results of `as.vector(BRA$Adj.Close)` and `index(BRA$Adj.Close)`.

Comment: @LegalizeIt - they're not rownames, they are a zoo index. `rownames` returns `NULL` for these data structures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To transform an `xts` object to a `data.frame`:

```
  data.frame(Date = index(BRA$Adj.Close), 
             coredata(BRA$Adj.Close))
```

Comment: @FlávioCorinthians Note that it is not an `xts` object anymore.

Answer (score 5):

You can't, the dates are more like rownames than columns.

You could coerce your object into a dataframe and then add acolumn like:

```
x <- as.data.frame(BRA$Adj.Close)
x$Date <- index(BRA$Adj.Close)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if what you want as the column `Date` are actually the row names of your data frame (if it is a data frame, that is).

If so, you can make the row names a column:

```
yourdataframe[2] = row.names(yourdataframe)
```

And then rename the column:

```
names(yourdataframe)[2] = "Dates"
```

If it is not a data frame already, convert it to one.

Comment: It's not a dataframe, it's a xts object. `rownames` just returns NULL on this, you need `index()`

Comment: `rownames` is more generic but `row.names` works as well for data frames